# Find 7 digit prime numbers with this property;

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

When you subtract the sum of the squares of the digits of the number  from the original number it gives you another prime number squared.

Comment: No offense, but I think it's bad policy to change the question (from 5 to 7-digit numbers) once answers have been attempted. If you wish to know the answer for 7-digit numbers, then post a separate question, or run the code with modified parameters.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

Okay, here's my solution:

```
for i in `primes 10000 100000`;do x=$(echo $i|python -c 'import sys, math;s = sys.stdin.read()[:-1]; p = math.sqrt(int(s) - sum(map(lambda x : int(x) * int(x), list(s))));                                                                                
if p % 1 == 0: print str(int(p))')
    if [ "$x" != "" ];then
        if  [ $(factor $x|awk '{ print NF }') -eq "2" ];then
                    echo $i
    fi
    fi
done
```

Ugly code, but I get:

```
18973
24763
37321
73561
96953
```

Let's check 37321. We get 37321 - 3² - 7² - 3² - 2² - 1², whose square root is 193, which is prime.

For 7 digits, here's what I have so far:

```
1100509
…
```

Let's check 1100509. We get sqrt(1100509 - 1 - 1 - 25 - 81) = 1049, which is prime. Feel free to expend more CPU cycles to get more.

Comment: Now these primes  should be classified  under  your and my name ,

Comment: 124 is not a prime and may numbers are missing.

Comment: Many numbers  are missing    true

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake. Let me fix it.

Comment: While you're fixing it, why mixing bash and python? Why not writing all in python (or just bash, if you're adventurous)?

Comment: Wait. In Vedran's solution, the numbers aren't prime. Have you listed the difference between the prime and the square of the prime there?

Comment: I think I'll stick to mine. And you really shouldn't switch it to 7 digits all of a sudden. Not fair!

Comment: Note that the OP asked for 7-digit primes.

Comment: @anorton OP edited the question.

Comment: @anorton: OP modified the question a few mins ago.

Comment: @user88221 Just noticed and fixed. In future, please put such comments under my answer. Better chances I see them.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @VedranŠego I don't have enough reputation to comment under your name. :-)

Comment: @user88221 I'm apologize then. That limitation makes very little sense to me, so I keep forgetting about it.

Answer (score 3):

The primes from $1000$ to $10^8$ with that property (and the corresponding root) are:

```
(2903,53)
(3533,59)
(3803,61)
(5197,71)
(9533,97)
(18973,137)
(24763,157)
(37321,193)
(73561,271)
(96953,311)
(113621,337)
(124777,353)
(129097,359)
(134837,367)
(139241,373)
(398341,631)
(830003,911)
(1100509,1049)
(1585201,1259)
(1661789,1289)
(2211257,1487)
(4541309,2131)
(4871077,2207)
(4897709,2213)
(5340949,2311)
(5958751,2441)
(7393123,2719)
(8185501,2861)
(8744003,2957)
(11485559,3389)
(15343039,3917)
(15343079,3917)
(16008193,4001)
(16459441,4057)
(16736519,4091)
(17648693,4201)
(17901563,4231)
(21077401,4591)
(22915511,4787)
(22915591,4787)
(25877861,5087)
(26553629,5153)
(28058447,5297)
(28058467,5297)
(30261149,5501)
(32137747,5669)
(33443269,5783)
(34304561,5857)
(36954461,6079)
(40360753,6353)
(43073159,6563)
(43309751,6581)
(47375963,6883)
(47596441,6899)
(48762557,6983)
(53743763,7331)
(56505481,7517)
(62141909,7883)
(65496941,8093)
(67782521,8233)
(76510171,8747)
(80982263,8999)
(82864927,9103)
(83302253,9127)
(84401197,9187)
(85027057,9221)
(86360003,9293)
(90992939,9539)
(95394619,9767)
(96373819,9817)
```

Code (Haskell):

```
module Main (main) where

import Math.NumberTheory.Primes
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers

import Control.Monad (guard)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let (lo,hi) = case args of
                    a:b:_ -> (read a, read b)
                    a:_   -> (1000, read a)
                    _     -> (1000, 10^7)
    mapM_ print $ funPrimes lo hi

digitSquareSum :: Integer -> Integer
digitSquareSum = go 0
  where
    go acc 0 = acc
    go acc m = case m `quotRem` 10 of
                 (q,r) -> go (acc + r*r) q

rootPrime :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
rootPrime n = do
    let m = n - digitSquareSum n
    r <- exactSquareRoot m
    guard (isPrime r)
    return r

funPrimes :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
funPrimes low high = takeWhile (<= high) (sieveFrom low) >>= \p ->
                                    case rootPrime p of
                                      Just r -> [(p,r)]
                                      Nothing -> []
```

Between $10^8$ and $10^9$, we have

```
(105411479,10267)
(110271107,10501)
(111492631,10559)
(111492671,10559)
(116014531,10771)
(116014571,10771)
(117787913,10853)
(117787993,10853)
(117961573,10861)
(120846227,10993)
(134258869,11587)
(148767061,12197)
(149793487,12239)
(156325123,12503)
(161010841,12689)
(161366489,12703)
(165199973,12853)
(166900837,12919)
(167780441,12953)
(169078339,13003)
(169234399,13009)
(171846139,13109)
(184878781,13597)
(187334143,13687)
(188485741,13729)
(199007723,14107)
(207043433,14389)
(207677111,14411)
(208023083,14423)
(209641673,14479)
(214300417,14639)
(218182633,14771)
(221384893,14879)
(235039859,15331)
(235899239,15359)
(238486597,15443)
(242082611,15559)
(247338829,15727)
(258020197,16063)
(258791927,16087)
(258791987,16087)
(262083953,16189)
(267944477,16369)
(270701371,16453)
(275792723,16607)
(276191479,16619)
(286320427,16921)
(286320487,16921)
(288354637,16981)
(288762337,16993)
(312193733,17669)
(312688781,17683)
(316519933,17791)
(319730353,17881)
(328298413,18119)
(343694849,18539)
(357928927,18919)
(359443943,18959)
(365612881,19121)
(368909131,19207)
(371217443,19267)
(371217463,19267)
(393744983,19843)
(399720367,19993)
(417916507,20443)
(424319009,20599)
(441798719,21019)
(454414673,21317)
(462981581,21517)
(472497401,21737)
(475371007,21803)
(486776309,22063)
(486952877,22067)
(487482577,22079)
(490932931,22157)
(500282917,22367)
(503598839,22441)
(508187159,22543)
(508457681,22549)
(511619333,22619)
(511709977,22621)
(520615621,22817)
(520615681,22817)
(524730821,22907)
(532271219,23071)
(562591219,23719)
(565155733,23773)
(575088641,23981)
(575088799,23981)
(622153489,24943)
(648364667,25463)
(658281941,25657)
(671794927,25919)
(671794987,25919)
(702939491,26513)
(726464467,26953)
(739350793,27191)
(744362309,27283)
(785737283,28031)
(808435721,28433)
(811851211,28493)
(863360941,29383)
(864419033,29401)
(878589319,29641)
(940097269,30661)
(949194871,30809)
(959946707,30983)
(968641477,31123)
(974876041,31223)
(978251059,31277)
(990801919,31477)
```

$111$ more. So these beasts are rare, but there are enough.

Comment: Enough for what Daniel ?

Comment: Enough for finding a bunch without starving while one waits.

Comment: Are you going to write a paper about them ?

Comment: I don't think so. They're nice curiosities, but I don't see what one could learn from them.

Comment: Have you heard of the book Prime curios  by  G.L. Hanaker .

Comment: No, although I know such books exist. And that __I__ don't see what one could learn from them doesn't mean I think there is nothing one could learn from them. I don't know if there is, I just don't see what it could be, so I don't see myself writing a paper about them.

Comment: What does one learn  from the study of the properties of Magic squares ?  Not much right .

Comment: I'm not versed in the history of the study of magic squares, but I seem to remember people found some interesting insights there. I expect that if the right person(s) investigate these primes, insights in the range from "mildly interesting" to "fascinating" would be gained. I just don't see myself among the "right persons" here (although I'm going to play around a bit, using other bases than $10$. As I said, they're nice curiosities, perhaps I'll find something, but don't hold your breath).

Answer (score 2):

My previous solution was not checking that the numbers are prime, just that $n - \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum\limits_{\text{digits $d$ of $n$}} d^2$ are.

So, in Mathematica:

```
n = 7;
Select[Range[10^(n - 1) + 1, 10^n - 1, 2],
  And[
    PrimeQ[#1],
    PrimeQ[Sqrt[#1 - Apply[Plus, IntegerDigits[#1]^2]]]
  ] &
]
```

Output:

```
{1100509, 1585201, 1661789, 2211257, 4541309, 4871077, 4897709,
5340949, 5958751, 7393123, 8185501, 8744003}
```

Comment: Now that many examples of this type of prime number have been fleshed out , now what ....  somebody  writes  a paper about these animals ?

Comment: For a paper to be accepted in any decent journal, there must be a bit more. It is very welcome that there is some use for them, or at least something interesting to learn. One cannot just make up a formula or a rule, find a bunch of numbers that fit it, and expect to publish a paper. A few minutes of programming is usually far from enough for a paper.

Comment: But it's a start , and you have to start somewhere Vedran.